# express.js parsing cookies?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, express

I am trying to use an old library balloons.io as a base for a chat app, but it's quite out dated, in this particular code I am trying to figure out how to use express 4x to parse the cookie to get an sid without getting it from the `req.session`

Since express 4x is not using `connect` anymore how can I do something similar to the below but in the new express version?

```
/*
 * Module dependencies
 */

var sio = require('socket.io')
  , parseCookies = require('connect').utils.parseSignedCookies
  , cookie = require('cookie')
  , fs = require('fs');

/**
 * Expose Sockets initialization
 */

module.exports = Sockets;

/**
 * Socket.io
 *
 * @param {Express} app `Express` instance.
 * @param {HTTPServer} server `http` server instance.
 * @api public
 */

function Sockets (app, server) {
  var config = app.get('config');
  var client = app.get('redisClient');
  var sessionStore = app.get('sessionStore');

  var io = sio.listen(server);
  io.set('authorization', function (hsData, accept) {
    if(hsData.headers.cookie) {
      var cookies = parseCookies(cookie.parse(hsData.headers.cookie), config.session.secret)
        , sid = cookies['balloons'];

      sessionStore.load(sid, function(err, session) {
        if(err || !session) {
          return accept('Error retrieving session!', false);
        }

        hsData.balloons = {
          user: session.passport.user,
          room: /\/(?:([^\/]+?))\/?$/g.exec(hsData.headers.referer)[1]
        };

        return accept(null, true);

      });
    } else {
      return accept('No cookie transmitted.', false);
    }
  });

  });

};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this helps, but Cookie parsing in express 4.x has been extracted to the `cookie-parser` package. I'm not sure, but you may be able to swap out `connect.util.parseSignedCookies` with cookieParser.parseSignedCookies`.

That's about all I can help you with, as I haven't used socket.io much yet.

Comment: Yeah I saw that, you're right. However I cannot figure out how to get the sid without the req object.

Comment: I'm not sure what hsData is, but if the value of sid is stored in the signed cookie 'balloons', and you have the secret available, then you should be able to get at its value somehow. Maybe try looking at the cookie-parser source and seeing which function does what.

Comment: What did you end up doing?

Comment: I answered it, basically `var cookies = cookie.parse(handshake.headers.cookie);
      var sid = cookieParser.signedCookie(cookies['balloons'], secrets.sessionSecret);`

Answer (score 0):

```
function Sockets (app, server, pub, sub, sessionStore) {
  var config = app.get('config');
  var secrets = require('./config/secrets');
  var client = pub;

  var io = sio.listen(server);
  io.set('authorization', function (handshake, callback) {

    if(handshake.headers.cookie) {

      // pay attention here, this is how you parse, make sure you use
      // cookie-parser and cookie
      var cookies = cookie.parse(handshake.headers.cookie);
      var sid = cookieParser.signedCookie(cookies['balloons'], secrets.sessionSecret);

      // get the session data from the session store
      sessionStore.load(sid, function(err, session) {
        if(err || !session) {
          return callback('Error retrieving session!', false);
        }

        // this is not storing the data into the handshake object
        handshake.headers.xygaming = {
          user: session.passport.user,
          room: /\/(?:([^\/]+?))\/?$/g.exec(handshake.headers.referer)[1]
        };

        return callback(null, true);

      });

    } else {
      return callback('No cookie transmitted.', false);
    }
  });

}
```